# editor templates, uihints in mvc4

Tags: jquery-ui, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I  ran into total confusion.

I am returning a Partial View to the below dynamic model which I will show in jQuery widget.

```
 @model dynamic
 @using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", null,  FormMethod.Post))
 {
   @Html.EditorForModel()

 --input type="submit" value="Edit" --
}
```

jquery script to show the view in pop up

```
$("#my-dialog").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    width: 400,
    resizable: false,
    modal: true
});

$(".modal").click(function () {
    $("#my-dialog").load(this.href, function () {
        $(this).dialog("open");
    });
    return false;
});
```

but my datetime picker is not showed in pop up partial view.

Can somebody advise what is wrong here?

Comment: Is the question not clear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The datetime picker display in the partial view has been solved by using the below script in my partial view:

$(".datetime").datetime();